# How can I calculate time of my main code?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I have a code which is included some functions. for every functions I use CPUTime. but in main model how can I calculate time. Please help me.

for example

```
using CPUTime
function Sminf2(ZB,ZT)
    model=CreateModel();
    WES=model[1];f1=model[2];f2=model[3];
    rf1=model[4];rf2=model[5];lf1=model[6];
    lf2=model[7];
    x=WES[:x];
    y=WES[:y];
   JuMP.setRHS(rf1,ZB[1]);
   JuMP.setRHS(lf1,ZT[1]);
   JuMP.setRHS(rf2,ZT[2]);
   JuMP.setRHS(lf2,ZB[2]);
   @objective(WES,Min,f2);
  status=solve(WES)
  return getvalue(x)
end
@time @CPUtime Sminf2(ZB,ZT)
```

## -----------------------------------------------------------------

but in this main code how can I calculate the time?

```
using JuMP,CPLEX,CPUTime
include("WEIGHT.juliarc (2).jl");
include("CreateModel.juliarc.jl");
include("Sminf2.juliarc.jl");
include("Sminf1.juliarc.jl");
pq=[];
model=CreateModel();
WES=model[1];f1=model[2];f2=model[3];
rf1=model[4];rf2=model[5];lf1=model[6];
lf2=model[7];ofv1=model[8];ofv2=model[9];
x=WES[:x];
y=WES[:y];
for i=1:5
     W=WEIGHT(Zb,Zt);
     pq=[pq;W[1]];
end
println("PQ=",pq)
```

## ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, it is recommended to use [BenchmarkTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl) for benchmarking a piece of code.

Paralleling the `@time` macro in `Base` Julia, `BenchmarkTools` exports the usually superior `@btime` macro, which, among other things, avoids measuring compilation time and performs a more precise statistical analysis. (see the package's documentation for details)

You can use it just as you use the `@time` macro, e.g. `@btime rand(2,2)`

To benchmark a block of code, such as your "main code", you could (and should) put that piece of code into a function or a `begin ... end` block. For example,

```
@btime begin
    # my code goes here
end
```

Note that, independent of benchmarking, it is anyways recommended to put performance critical code into functions, as is explained in the [Performance Tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html#Avoid-global-variables-1) in Julia's documentation.

Having introduced `@btime`, of course, if the runtime of your code dominates over compilation time, as should probably be the case when benchmarking the whole code ("main code"), it's often nonetheless fine to use `@time`. It should be instructive to read [this recent discourse thread](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/what-does-allocation-mean-when-creating-a-new-array/19122) where parts of how to use `@time` correctly have been discussed.